# Refer to an other columns value in a MVC3 Razor WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I have a webgrid presenting data grouped by weeks. The first grid column contains the weeknumber as seen below in the code example.
The last "Summary" column needs to show different content depending on if the rows weeknumber match the current weeknumber or not.
Is it possible to use the Weeknumber column value from them Summary column in some way?

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "grid", headerStyle: "head",columns: trainingGrid.Columns(
  grid.Column("WeekNumber", "Week"),
  .....
  grid.Column("Summary", "Sum", format: (item) =>
    { if (***above columns weeknumber == ViewBag.CurrentWeekNo)
      { return "Dolor"
      }
      else{
        return "Sit";
      }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548109%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) format method's parameter you get the current item as a dynamic object so you can access WeekNumber with normal property syntax:

```
grid.Column("Summary", "Sum", format: (item) =>
{
    if (item.WeekNumber == ViewBag.CurrentWeekNo)
    {
        return "Dolor";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Sit";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx for helping! IntelliSense did not show me Weeknumber when I typed "item." but it worked :)

Comment: @Jay `item` is `dynamic` in this case, not strongly typed. IntelliSense can't show its properties, because it doesn't know what they are. Think of `dynamic` as akin to VB's `Variant` type or JavaScript's `var`.

Comment: What if I wanted to compare the value of the same column, but from a different row?

Comment: @user3281466 you can only get the current item. So you cannot compare to a different row.